# Background position not fixed on page

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm build react app with multiple components and i have problem with background image: it moving up/down when i add any rows in table (on div tags). Temporary fixing: changing background-position property. Below some code:

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import Header from './components/Header'
import TournamentsTable from './components/TournamentsTable'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="background"></div>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Header />
        <TournamentsTable />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

styles

```css
#background {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2000px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url('/images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #111111;
    background-position: center -440px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to make sure your Body has taken the entire page:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh
}
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #111111 url('/images/background.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

and then add "background-attachment" in your style:

```
#background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        background: #111111 url('/images/background.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        opacity: 0.6;


    }
```